# Performing logical OR between multiple CSVs with 32 bit hex values using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, csv

I am trying to read multiple (50+) CSV files within the same folder using MATLAB. These CSVs contain 3 32 bit hex values and the format of the data is the same for all files. Each CSV contains the data within 2 rows and 3 columns with no headers. For e.g.

00000800,D404002C,4447538F

000008FF,D404002C,4447538F

After ORing the 2 rows from all files, the final 2 rows of 3 32 bit hex values need to be written out to a CSV.

Now, before jumping in the deep end trying to process multiple files, I have started by just trying to OR Row 1 with Row 2 of the same file. So, 00000800|  000008FF , D404002C | D404002C.. I have been able to convert them to binary and do a logical OR between the 3 values however currently have the following issues:

1) If the MSB of the hex value starts with 3 or 4 (binary 0011 or 0100) then the leading 0's are missed or if the second hex value happens to be 800 then the leading 00000's are missed.

2) I cannot convert the integer cell array back to hex

I have seen many posts about just reading CSVs using MATLAB or separating the data and etc on stackoverflow and matlabcentral however not been able to interpret any of them to sort my issue. Any help would be much appreciated.Below is what I have so far:

```
fid = fopen('File1.csv');
c = textscan(fid,'%s','Delimiter','\n');
fclose(fid);

contents = c{1};

row1 = strsplit(contents{1},',','CollapseDelimiters',0);
row2 = strsplit(contents{2},',','CollapseDelimiters',0);

x = 1;
y = 1;

while x <= length(row1)     
 column1{x} = hex2dec(row1(x));
 column2{x} = hex2dec(row2(x));
 x = x + 1;
end

while y <= length(column1)

 bin1{y} = zeros(1,32);
 bin2{y} = zeros(1,32);

 bin1{y} = dec2bin(column1{y});
 bin2{y} = dec2bin(column2{y});
 result{y} = bitor(bitget(uint8(bin1{y}),1),bitget(uint8(bin2{y}),1));
 y = y+ 1 ;
end
```

Also, eventually need to be able to do this process with multiple CSVs so I have attached link to File1.csv and File2.csv if someone wants to try to OR row 1 of File1 with row 2 of File2.csv and so on.

[CSV Files](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B0VyFt-6tDwCaXNxVjVYTTEyZkU&usp=sharing)

Apologies if I have missed anything, Please leave a comment and I'll try to explain it further.

Thanks!

EDIT: Hope the image below explains what I am trying to do better.

[image: Description Support]

Comment: What do you mean with _the final 2 rows of 3 32 bit hex values need to be written out to a CSV_: as far as I've udestand the first part of the question, if you "OR" the two line of a file you should get either 1 row with 3 values or 3 row with one value each. Could you please explain?

Comment: Sorry, let me explain. With the code I have posted above, I am trying to OR 2 rows from the same file and yes you're correct i will only get 1 row with 3 values or if I wanted 3 rows with 1 value each. 

However, this is only the first part of my attempt to solve the actual problem.

Ultimately, I want to OR row 1 of x number of CSV's together and row 2 of x number of CSVs together so I will end up with 1 CSV with 2 rows with 3 values each. I have added a link to 2 CSV files if someone wants to attempt this, which then I will try to use with X no. of CSVs.

Hope this makes more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following approach:

- use the `dir` function to get the list of files to be processed
- create a loop to go through the files to be processed. In the loop

  - read the input files
  - convert the hexadecimal values read from the files into a matrix of characters using the `char` function
  - convert the data stored in the char matrinx from `hex` to `dec` and then to `uint32` using the functions `hex2dec` and `uint32`
  - perform the `or` using the `bitor` function
- go to next iteration
- at the end of the loop, write the output

The above described approach has been implemented in the folowing code:

```
% Get the list of CSV files
hex_files=dir('O_File*.csv');
% Open the outpur file
fp_out=fopen('new_hex_file.csv','wt');
% Loop over the CSV files
for i=1:length(hex_files)
   % Read the i-th CSV file
   fid = fopen(hex_files(i).name);
   c = textscan(fid,'%s','Delimiter','\n');
   fclose(fid);
   % Get the 2 rows
   contents = c{1};
   row_1=char(strsplit(contents{1},',','CollapseDelimiters',0));
   row_2=char(strsplit(contents{2},',','CollapseDelimiters',0));
   % Convert from hex to uint32
   row_d_1=uint32(hex2dec(row_1));
   row_d_2=uint32(hex2dec(row_2));
   if(i == 1)
      % Store the row of the first file and continue
      tmp_var_1=row_d_1;
      tmp_var_2=row_d_2;
      continue
   else
      % OR the two rows
      tmp_var_1=bitor(tmp_var_1,row_d_1);
      tmp_var_2=bitor(tmp_var_2,row_d_2);
   end
end
% Write the OR values into the new file
fprintf(fp_out,'%08X,%08X,%08X\n',tmp_var_1);
fprintf(fp_out,'%08X,%08X,%08X\n',tmp_var_2);
% Close the output file
fclose(fp_out);
```

The following input files have been used to test it:

**File1.csv**

```
00000800,D404002C,4447538F
000008FF,D404002C,4447538F
```

**File2.csv**

```
000008FF,D404DD2C,49475115
11100800,D411EC2C,3ACD1266
```

**File3.csv**

```
123456FF,ABCDEF2C,369ABC15
01012369,00110033,36936966
```

The output is:

```
12345EFF,FFCDFF2C,7FDFFF9F
11112BFF,D415EC3F,7EDF7BEF
```

Hope this helps.

Qapla'

Comment: Thank you very much for above. Whilst most of it makes sense to me, I do not quite understand whats going on with file set 1 and file set 2 ? Also, second MSB of row 1,column 1 from file set 2_1 already has an A (1010) so how does the second MSB in the final output for Row 1 column 1 only has 3 ? 
I have added an image to my original post above and hope thats what you understood from my description  about what I am trying to do. 
Meanwhile, I will try and run / modify what you have posted above.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've misunderstood the way the input file have to be processed; the picture you've inserted made it clear. I've update the code in the answer. I've added a third input file (the first two input files are the ones you've posted) to thest the loop. Hope now the code is working.

Comment: Please ignore my previous comment. 5 Min time limit means I cant edit it anymore. I debugged the script and turns out as the code was trying to get the rows even after it had ran out of files (i = 33 for this instance) it was causing that issue. Now, I'm using while loop instead of for and  manually incrementing var i within the loop and it seems to work fine now. Thank you very much for your efforts.